# Prove that exists a vector n-dimensional $x \neq 0$ such that $(A^2+B^2)x=0$ for two different square matrices $n\times n$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ and $B$ be two different square matrices $n\times n$. If $A^3=B^3$ and $A^2B=B^2A$. Prove that exists a vector n-dimensional $x \neq 0$ such that $(A^2+B^2)x=0$.

My first thought was that $(A^2+B^2)$ should be equal to $0$ as $x \neq 0$, but then I realize that with matrices this is not true. For example: if we have the matrix $$C=\begin{bmatrix}1&2&3\\1&2&3\\1&2&3\end{bmatrix}$$
Then we should find a vector $x \neq 0$ such that $Cx=0$. $$\begin{bmatrix}1&2&3\\1&2&3\\1&2&3\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix}=x_1\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}+x_2\begin{bmatrix}2\\2\\2\end{bmatrix}+x_3\begin{bmatrix}3\\3\\3\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$$ So a possible answer might be $$x=\begin{bmatrix}3\\3\\-3\end{bmatrix}$$ proving that the matrix is not necessarily equal to $0$.

I am not sure how I should use the fact that $A^3=B^3$ and $A^2B=B^2A$.

Comment: What have you tried? What do you understand? What are you still confused about?

Comment: Please post any thoughts you've had. Maybe you've tried something that didn't work. Posting it will help people from also trying the same thing, or offhandedly suggesting without trying themselves that you go and try the thing that didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, prove that since $A$ and $B$ are different there must be a vector $\mathbf{x}$ with $A\mathbf{x} \neq B\mathbf{x}$.  This means that $\mathbf{v} = A\mathbf{x} - B\mathbf{x} \neq \mathbf{0}$. Now show that $(A^2+B^2)\mathbf{v} = \mathbf{0}$.  For this, you will need the hypotheses on $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Show that $$(A^2+B^2)A=(A^2+B^2)B$$
What could we then do if $A^2+B^2$ was invertible?